# JavaScript : Find (and Replace) text that is NOT in a specific HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

**TL;DR; Summary**

How do I inject a <span> around a specific word or phrase found in the HTML of the current page **BUT** ignore any text which is **ALREADY** contained within the same span I am trying to inject.

*Due to the large number of values being processed, this must be high performance!*

**Example:**

*Searching for "foo"*

Should find a match:

<p>This sentence contains a foo bar value</p>

Should **NOT** find a match:

<p>This sentence contains a <span class='widget'>foo bar</span> value</p>

**Background - i.e. Why?**

I am looking into a specific problem of having to inject a <span class='widget'> element around specific text found on a page dynamically. The text I am looking for is in a large array.

- Array of text strings to look for is in the thousands
- Text values can contain phrases or words
- phrases must take precedence over words

This last one is a killer. 
For example:

- I have two values "foo bar" and "foo"
- I want to process the sentence: "This is a foo bar sentence"

After I have finished processing then ..

**Desired Output**

"This is a <span class='widget'>foo bar</span> sentence"

**NOT Desired**

"This is a <span class='widget'>foo <span class='widget'>bar</span></span> sentence"

Now .. the first step in achieving this is to sort my array by length (process the longest ones first). But the problem is that after processing my find-replace logic is still finding the smaller "word" inside the (already processed) phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, and only if, there are no nested `<span>`-tags, you can search for

`/(<span\b[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/span>)|(\b(?:foo|bar)(?:\s+(?:foo|bar))*)/g` and replace it with the function

```
function matchEvaluator(_, span, word) {
    if (span) return span;
    return '<span class="widget">' + word + '</span>';
}
```

- the part `(<span\b[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/span>)` searches for the span element.
  That's the part, where no nested `<span>`-element is allowed. The matched text is returnd unchanged (the reason to match them is to consume all the characters inside `<span>`)
- `<span\b[^>]*>` searches for the start tag - this could be not sufficient for your needs. Maybe you'll try to be more specific, e.g. something like `<span\b(?:\s+\w[\w-]*(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\S*)))*>`
- `(\b(?:foo|bar)(?:\s+(?:foo|bar))*)` searches for the words "foo" and "bar"
  If there is one, it searches for space characters and another "foo"
  or "bar" (repeatedly).
  Since the `<span>`-tags and all their content is already consumed, you can only match "foo" and "bar" outside `<span>`
- the matchEvaluator-function tests, if a span element is matched and if so, simply returns the matched text. Otherwise, the words are matched and they are returned wrapped into the new span..

---

Test:

```
var texts = [
    "This is a foo bar sentence",
    "This sentence contains a <span class='widget'>foo bar</span> value"
];

var wordsOutsideSpan_rx = /(<span\b[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/span>)|(\b(?:foo|bar)(?:\s+(?:foo|bar))*)/g;
function wrapInSpan(_, span, word) {
    if (span) return span;
    return '<span class="widget">' + word + '</span>';
}

texts.forEach(function (txt) {
     console.log(txt.replace(wordsOutsideSpan_rx, wrapInSpan));
});

// outputs
// "This is a <span class="widget">foo bar</span> sentence"
// "This sentence contains a <span class='widget'>foo bar</span> value"
```

Comment: This doesn't meet my requirements. I need to match JUST the word UNLESS it is contained within a span element WITH A SPECIFIC CLASS. Might have to resort to some kind of jQuery wizardry as well to do this .. not sure.

Comment: I did test your RegEx and it not only checks for ANY span, but it then matches the entire span (not what I wanted). Note - the span might contain more than just the words I'm looking for!

Comment: You want to find and replace - that is what is done above. The regex, indeed, matches more than that.

It matches the whole span and returns it unchanged in the `matchEvaluator` function. Additionally, it matches the words you search for (not in the span!) - and these words are returned wrapped in a `<span>`.

So I think it does what you are looking for...

Comment: I also need to match words appearing in OTHER spans which have a different class.

Comment: If you can ensure it's `<span class='widget'>` (or another, but fixed form) you can solve it by replacing `<span\b[^>]*>` by `<span class='widget'>`. To be a bit more generic, you can use e.g. `<span\b[^>]*?class=['"][^'"]*?\bwidget\b[^>]+>`

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's another way.

I'm using jQuery to find the elements (not really needed, but it's convenient).
This solution accepts nested `<span>`'s, and maybe it's even faster. Please share your results.

```js
(function () {
    var testwords_rx = /\b(?:foo|bar)\b/; // it's annoying, but should be faster
    var words_rx = /\b(?:foo|bar)\b(?:\s+(?:foo|bar)\b)?/g;

    function filterTextElement(idx, element) {
        return element != null &&
               element.nodeType == 3 && // #text node
               element.nodeValue.match(testwords_rx); // find at least one match
    }

    function wrapFoobars(idx, element) {
        var lastPos = 0;
        var text = element.nodeValue;
        var parent = element.parentNode;

        function addUnwrapped(start, end) {
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(text.substring(start, end));
            parent.insertBefore(textNode, element);
        }

        function addWrapped(start, end) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.className = 'widget';
            span.style.border = "1px solid red";

            var txtprop = 'textContent' in span ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
            span[txtprop] = text.substring(start, end);

            parent.insertBefore(span, element);
        }

        function splitAndWrapText(words, pos) {
            if (pos > lastPos) {
                addUnwrapped(lastPos, pos);
            }

            lastPos = pos + words.length;
            addWrapped(pos, lastPos);
        }

        text.replace(words_rx, splitAndWrapText);
        if (lastPos < text.length) {
            addUnwrapped(lastPos, text.length);
        }

        parent.removeChild(element);
    }

    $('body *')
        .filter(':not(.widget, .widget *)')
        .contents()
        .filter(filterTextElement)
        .each(wrapFoobars)
    ;
})();
```

### How does it work

- `$('body *').filter(':not(.widget, .widget *)')`

  Select all tags inside `<body>` and filter out `.widget`-elements and all their descendants (change this to only select the elements you need)
- `.contents()`

  get all the children of the matched elements (including text-nodes)
- `.filter(filterTextElement)`

  filter to get only #text-elements with at least one of the words you search for
- `wrapFoobars`:
  replace over the matches. The text before the first, in between and after the last match must be inserted as text node (`addUnwrapped`), the matched text itself is wrapped into a newly created `<span>`-Element (`addWrapped`).
  At the end, the original text element is deleted (`parent.removeChild(element);`)