# Regex JS. New line for each dot, but only outside of a quotation

Tags: javascript, regex

This is very strong for me. I give up, after two days, I ask you

Turn this

```
var str = 'The quick "brown. fox". jumps over. "the lazy dog"'
var str2 = 'The quick «brown. fox». jumps over. «the lazy dog»'
```

Into this

```
The quick "brown. fox".
jumps over.
"the lazy dog"
```

or

```
The quick «brown. fox». 
jumps over. 
«the lazy dog»
```

In other words I would like to wrap every dot, but this should not happen if the dot is inside a quote.

Comment: This is not something that lends itself to regex processing. The structure is similar to CSV processing, and if you search on here for "regex csv quotes" you'll find any number of answers suggesting looking for alternatives rather than use regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
var re = /(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)\./g;
var r;

r = str.replace(/(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)\./g, '.\n');
 The quick "brown. fox".
 jumps over.
 "the lazy dog"

r = str2.replace(re, '.\n');
 The quick «brown.
 fox».
 jumps over.
 «the lazy dog»
```

`(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)` is a lookahead that makes sure there are even number of quotes following dot thus making sure dot is outside the quotes. However note that quotes should be balanced and unescaped.

Comment: @anubhava Awesome, helped me split a CSV correctly where fields contained newline character which are outside the quotes!

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach (like in [JavaScript : Find (and Replace) text that is NOT in a specific HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239956/javascript-find-and-replace-text-that-is-not-in-a-specific-html-element/30241940#30241940)), this could be solved by matching both, the quoted string and the desired period.

In the replace-function you then have the chance to change only the single periods...

```
txt.replace(/("[^"]*"|«[^»]*»)|(\.)/g, function (_, quoted, dot) {
    if (quoted) return quoted;
    return '.\n';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With match

```
str.match(/((?:"[^"]*"|«[^»]+»|[^".«]+)+(?:\.|$))\s*/g).join("\n")

"The quick "brown. fox". 
jumps over. 
"the lazy dog""

str2.match(/((?:"[^"]*"|«[^»]+»|[^".«]+)+(?:\.|$))\s*/g).join("\n")

"The quick «brown. fox». 
jumps over. 
«the lazy dog»"
```